# update data with left join after filter

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I have a data like below:

```
x1 <- data.frame(names = c('a','b', NA, NA, 'd'),
             match = c('a1', 'a2', 'a10', 'a10', 'a4'), 
             value = rnorm(5))
x2 <- data.frame(match = c('a10','a11'), value = rnorm(2))
```

I wanna fill x1 "value" with x2 "value" when x1 names are NA, fake code like this:

```
x1 %>% 
  mutate( value = ifelse(is.na(names), left_join(x2, by = 'match'), value)).
```

It throws error info :

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument "y" is missing, with no default.
```

I know it's because left_join problem, but i don't know how to code it correctly. Gennerally, how can i update data after filter with left_join (or valuemaps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably easier to do `left_join` first, and then replace numbers in `value` based on `names`. `x3` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

x1 <- data_frame(names = c('a','b', NA, NA, 'd'),
                 match = c('a1', 'a2', 'a10', 'a10', 'a4'), 
                 value = rnorm(5))
x2 <- data_frame(match = c('a10','a11'), value = rnorm(2))

x3 <- x1 %>%
  left_join(x2, by = "match") %>%
  mutate(value.x = ifelse(is.na(names), value.y, value.x)) %>%
  select(names, match, value = value.x)
```

Comment: if do left_join first it will fill all values matches names in x2, which is not I desired. I did not put it in the example, but what if x1 first match is a 10 not a1? Then it will replace the original value which I wish to keep.@ycw

Comment: @VincentLin No, it will not. After `left_join`, `value` column in `x1` is renamed to `vlaue.x`, while `value` column in `x2` is renamed to `value.y`, No any replacement yet. Replacement only happens after the `mutate` call.

Comment: thanks, you're right, i didn't view the code carefully

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `data.table` where we converted the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(x1)`), join `on` 'match' and assign the 'value' column of 'x2' i.e. 'i.value' to 'value' of 'x1'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x1)[x2, value := i.value, on = .(match)]
x1
#   names match      value
#1:     a    a1 -0.5458808
#2:     b    a2  0.5365853
#3:    NA   a10 -0.3432662
#4:    NA   a10 -0.3432662
#5:     d    a4  0.8474600
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
x1 <- data.frame(names = c('a','b', NA, NA, 'd'),
         match = c('a1', 'a2', 'a10', 'a10', 'a4'), 
         value = rnorm(5))
set.seed(49)
x2 <- data.frame(match = c('a10','a11'), value = rnorm(2))
```